# Magento 1.9.2.4 + Redis

Tags: ce-1.9.2.4, redis

I am currently running Magento 1.9.2.4 + Redis.
And I want to dubbel check my current settings.

Therefore I changed my local.xml with `<full_page_cache><backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend></full_page_cache>`.

But after that I wrote that it is better for Magento 1.8+ to use `<full_page_cache><backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend></full_page_cache>` am I right?

Should I enable `Cm_RedisSession.xml` inside app/etc/modules?
Because that is disabled by default.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable the Cm_RedisSession if you plan on storing session data in redis. It is however not necessary for cache.

Comment: Also, are you running community edition? Because that has no support for full page cache. So in that case you should probably change <full_page_cache> into <cache>. Also just checked  my own redis conf on a 1.9+. It runs with Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis. It seems to work very fine with that.